Freshly Imaged a Computer and Path did not Exist in Registry
Is it possible that the HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce path does not exist  when a computer is freshly imaged? I tried running this script on a fresh installation of Windows 11 and it was not present:
Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce (New-Guid) @'
powershell.exe -noprofile -c Restart-Computer -Force"
'@

Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

Restart-Computer -Force

So to mitigate this I added this block above that portion of the PowerShell Script:
$home_path = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"

if(-NOT (Test-Path -Path $home_path)){
    New-Item $home_path -Force | Out-Null
}

My question primarily stems from the design of the OS, and if it's present there in freshly imaged products.

Is it possible for a registry key associated with the current user to not exist, it’s definitely possible, if that user was never logged into.

@Ramhound So if I understand correctly, sounds like something I did, because I made the account logged in and tried to run the script and got an error message saying that the path for registry did not exist. So would it be valid of me to create it to mitigate if the path is not created?

What I know about that key is limited, it probably is one of those keys, where whatever is first to require it actually creates it. That certainly is the case for other keys I am familiar with.

Read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys and here: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/14zfq49/run_once_registry/?rdt=51301. You are merely telling it to restart the computer. Seems odd to restart once on every profile signed on, but perhaps your configuration, environment, and software requires this once per profile, but seems like an odd one that may just be the workaround to some problem it always resolves. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you have slews of options, just fit in accordingly for your specific need.
